# What's the better way of accessing an inner bound class method in C#?

Tags: c#, class, properties

What is the better and optimized way of accessing an inner bound class,

1. **Via a public property**

   ```
   class MyClass1
   {
       public MyClass2 m_myClass2 { get; set; }

       public MyClass1(MyClass2 myClass2)
       {
           m_myClass2 = myClass2;
       }
   }

   class MyClass2
   {
       public void MyClass2Method()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
       }
   }

   class MyClass3
   {
       public void MyClass3Method(MyClass1 myClass1)
       {
           myClass1.m_myClass2.MyClass2Method();
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Via a method call**

   ```
   class MyClass1
   {
       private readonly MyClass2 m_myClass2;

       public MyClass1(MyClass2 myClass2)
       {
           m_myClass2 = myClass2;
       }

       public void MyClass1AccessMyClass2Method()
       {
           m_myClass2.MyClass2Method();
       }
   }

   class MyClass2
   {
       public void MyClass2Method()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
       }
   }

   class MyClass3
   {
       public void MyClass3Method(MyClass1 myClass1)
       {
           myClass1.MyClass1AccessMyClass2Method();
       }
   }
   ```

What is the best practice of calling the method **MyClass2Method** of **MyClass2**, via the class **MyClass3**. MyClass2 is not referenced in MyClass3.

**Way 1** or **Way 2**?

Comment: I'd recommend using an interface and giong in the direction of "Way 2" but using the interface rather than concrete classes. MyClass3 does not care how it is done inside MyClass1 and it shouldn't need to care (which it would with "Way 1").

Comment: Can you explain what makes Way 2 more suited than Way 1? Or at least a reference of such an explanation?

Comment: You're asking about "better", "optimized" and "best practice", all of which is quite opinion-based. Are you concerned about a specific aspect? What do these classes actually represent? What do you know about OO design principles? What did your research show?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have made the context so narrow by providing an example, to avoid it being vague. I don't expect a personal opinion, I just expect an OO Design principal that addresses this kind of a pattern!

Comment: The issue here is that it depends. Is the other class, the one you can reach through the property, more of a detail in the overall implementation? Then hide it behind new methods and properties on the surface object. Is it an integral part serving a function on its own? Then surface it out through properties or method calls (ie. return the object). There's not going to be an answer that says "Always do X" for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are bumping into a software principle called [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), which basically is the principle of least knowledge as possible ( practical )

Generally it's better to only access methods on Myclass1 with no knowledge any other class exists at all.

Even better might be through an interface depending on the actual context .

Answer (score 1):

An example for what I wrote in the comment:

```
interface DancesWithWolves
{
    void DanceWithWolves();
}

class MyClass2 : DancesWithWolves
{
    public void DanceWithWolves() { /* ... */ }
}

class MyClass1 : DancesWithWolves
{
    private readonly DancesWithWolves m_myClass2;

    public MyClass1(DancesWithWolves myClass2)
    {
        m_myClass2 = myClass2;
    }

    public void DanceWithWolves()
    {
        m_myClass2.DanceWithWolves();
    }
}

class MyClass3
{
     public void MyClass3Method(DancesWithWolves myClass1)
     {
        myClass1.DanceWithWolves();
     }
}
```

This not only hides MyClass2 from MyClass3 but gives you the opportunity to later exchange the behavior of MyClass1 by simply injecting another implementation of the interface.

Keith already mentioned the Law of Demeter in his answer, which is also worth reading if you want to figure out why you should be using interfaces and avoid strong dependencies as you would have with "way 1".

Note: This is not a "do it *always* like this" - there *can* be situations where you actually *want to* return the instance of "MyClass2" to a client. My answer is based on the example code you've given and thus assuming that this is not the case here. (See Lasse's comment if you are confused now ;) )

Answer (score 1):

This all has do to with abstraction, and because I like bad comparisons, I'll compare it to a car.

To start the car, you need the combustion engine to fire:

```
public class Car
{
    private IEngine _engine;

    public Car(IEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }

    public void StartMoving()
    {
        if (_engine is CombustionEngine ce)
       {
            ce.FireSparkPlugs();
       }
       else
       {
            // ...
       }
    }
}
```

Now consider the alternative, where you return the innards of the car to the caller (whether you do that through a method or a property doesn't matter):

```
public class Car
{
    private IEngine _engine;

    public Car(IEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }

    public IEngine GetEngine()
    {
        return _engine;
    }
}
```

Now the *caller* will have to know what kind of engine the car has to get it to move, while they shouldn't have, because they're dealing with the vehicle on the level of abstraction: a vehicle. They just want the vehicle to start moving, they don't want to know how the vehicle actually moves.

Now you can't change the kind of engine you pass into the car, because then the caller will break.

On the other hand, if you want the caller to be able to inspect the engine, because that makes sense for certain operations on the car, then sure, you could expose it.

Comment: I like bad comparisons, too :D +1 Some downvotes simply remain a mystery.